# Package scrlayer-scrpage breaks scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm trying to change the standard footer of the scrlttr2 class from *{page no.}* to *Page {page no.} of {total}*. While searching for a way to do this, I found out that the current accepted method for KOMA classes is to use the scrlayer-scrpage package. However, loading that package raises the following error:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \z@ 
l.7 \end{letter}
```

Here is the really minimal (non-)working example used to create this error:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
This is a MWE.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions? Are scrlttr2 and scrlayer-scrpage incompatible or could something be wrong with my package (versions)?

Comment: Works for me. Could you please check if your distribution is up-to-date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does work with old KOMA-Script 3.22, [current KOMA-Script release 3.23](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) or [current KOMA-Script prerelease](https://komascript.de/current). Nevertheless, you do not need `scrlayer-scrpage` to change the page mark, you only need to redefine command `\pagemark`:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage\ of
    \letterlastpage}}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering \pagemark}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
  \opening{Hello,}
  \lipsum
  \closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you prefer

[image]

add

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\footskip\relax}
\makeatother
```

to the document preamble.

Comment: Thanks, I was using KOMA v3.12. Updating to the current version solved the problem, but your solution also seems to work.